# both mouse "click" and "click-drag n release" to shft div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The very first click slides d div d1 to right side. Nw only for the left-side slide i want both mouse "click" and "click-drag and release" to the original location. I can slide the div  d1 to its original location by a click only but i want it to shift by click-drag and release also.

In simple words
In my given code below i want to further slide div with id d1 back to same original location   which has to be done by mouse click-drag-release method. Remember this will happen after div d1 position has been changed by clicking on div d2.

```
<html>
<head><title></title><script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> //<![CDATA[

$(document).ready(function(){   $("#d2").click(function(){
   if($("#d1").css("left") <="-131px") 
        {
       $("#d1").animate({left:'250px'});        
        }   
     else   {
    $("#d1").animate({left:'-131px'});      
                }   
  }); 

  $('#d1').draggable({
cursor: 'move',
containment: '#dd'      // sets to can be dragged only within its parent
 }); 



  });

  //]]> </script>

</head>
<body>
<div style="width:531px;height:301px; background:#a7daa8;">
<div id="dd" style="width:530px;height:300px;">
<div id="d1" style="position:absolute; left:-131px;">
<div style="float:left; background:#a90000;" >hidden div on left------</div>
<div id="d2"  style=" float:left;background:#ccc; height: 300px;" >click here to slide the div</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to click to animate the div to one place, and then be able to drag it back to where it came from, try this here: http://jsfiddle.net/xLBBP/8/

The click handler for the animation is the same, but now also makes the div draggable after it is clicked. Dragging is limited to the x axis. You can then drag the div around, if you drag it back near enough to where it came from then it'll animate back to its original position. I also moved the css to the css pane and made some amendments, which may fix the problems you were having in a mobile browser (it might not though...).

I've added a variable to keep track of whether the user is dragging or not, to prevent the mouseup at the end of the drag triggering the animation back to the original position. So now you can drag the div back to its original position, or click on it to trigger the animation back to its original position.

There is also now a variable snapBackDistance so you can set the distance from its original starting position that it will animate back from if you drag and then release. You can play around with it to set a value that you are happy with.

```
var isDragging = false;
var snapBackDistance = -125;

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#d2").click(function(){
        if (!$('#d1').is('.ui-draggable-dragging')){
            if(isDragging == false){
                 $("#d1").animate({left:'-131px'});   
            }   
            isDragging = false;
        }
        if($("#d1").css("left") <="-131px"){
            $("#d1").animate({left:'131px'});
            $("#d1").draggable({ 
                axis: "x",
                start: function( event, ui ) {
                    isDragging = true;
                },
                stop: function( event, ui ) {
                    if(parseInt($("#d1").css("left")) < snapBackDistance){
                        $("#d1").animate({left:'-131px'});
                        $("#d1").draggable("destroy");
                    }
                }
            });
        }   
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I have made some changes to my question above for better understanding and also have added a question which is another issue i m facing

Comment: OK, so do you mean you just want to be able to drag it back to its original location? If so, what do you want to happen if someone drags it only partially the way back?

Comment: 1st ans - Yes click as well as drag back should be the two options . 2nd ans- I mean if someone drags it to a distance only then it should be  back to its original location. that distance could be close to 50 %